# cv::Mat Per-element inverse

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there per-element inverse opencv function for `cv::Mat`?

Example:

```
|a , b , c|
|d , e , f|
|g , h , i|
```

Output:

```
|1/a , 1/b , 1/c|
|1/d , 1/e , 1/f|
|1/g , 1/h , 1/i|
```

Comment: isn't this more a "per-element division" ? aka: `divide(Mat::ones(), src,dst);`

Comment: stupid me... many thanks. please make it an answer sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will simply be `1.0f / mat`.

Example:

```
cv::Mat mat = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 1, 2, 3, 
                                        4, 5, 6, 
                                        7, 8, 9);
mat = 1.0f / mat;
```

Afterwards, `mat` will be

```
[1, 0.5, 0.33333334;
 0.25, 0.2, 0.16666667;
 0.14285715, 0.125, 0.11111111]
```